# Effective Qt layout management

Tags: qt4, qt-designer, qlayout

Looks like layouts in Qt are quite powerful and flexible, but sometimes not very intuitive. I must fiddle sometimes to get a desired widgets layout. Maybe i have wrong approach?

Look at this form:

[image]

1. The layout a made is form's layout - a cannot see its edges and i could not find any settings in Qt Designer for this.
2. The space between labels and their widgets (which i prefer to place above the widgets, not on the left side of them) is too big. I can set `maximum` size for them or i can make sublayouts for each label and its widget - but is this the way to go?
3. Looks like this layout has several columns. Can i add/delete a column/row from the layout without breaking it and making it again? How to i do this the best way? The left most column is narrower the the second column - setting the minimum width of one of the widgets from the left most column didn't help.

I've been looking in Internet for articles on how to make good layouts in Qt Designer. Do you have any links?
Would you please share your techniques on working with Qt layouts?

Comment: The first column is narrower because of the width of the "Repayments count" label in the second column.

Answer (score 1):

1. To get layout properties select widget, which contain layout, (in right-top object explorer, for example) and scroll down properties (right-bottom) list. At the end of the list you'll find it.
2. Space are set up by properties layoutHorizontal|VerticalSpacing. Also you can set margin|padding for each widget in layout via stylesheets.
3. Layout's columns and rows count calculate automatically. Adding or removing widget from form will add or remove column or row in layout if that widget was last in column|row. If you want reallocate widgets in layout you can play with row|column stretch (layout properties) to do some column|row bigger or smaller or add spacers to layout. Enjoy =)

P.S. For build complex form I recommend to use QGridLayout. It is powerful and allow to construct splendid widgets and forms.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 1. I know how to view the properties, but i was looking for a way to `view` layout's borders. 2. Will try this. 3. Will check this. P.S. I `am` using `QGridLayout` in the shown example.